# I cannot use Android support libraries or Play Services via Gradle in one of my projects

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to add the support libraries to my app by putting this in the dependencies section of build.gradle:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
```

This works fine in all my libgdx apps except for one of them. It simply cannot find the library. It says:

```
Error:Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/MyName/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
    file:/C:/Users/MyName/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
```

I tried this with the Android support libraries as well, and they have the same issue.

local.properties is pointing to the android sdk just as it is in my other projects.

I see that its searching the Android SDK's local Maven repository for it. But the directory as listed above in the error does not exist. The .m2/repository directory exists with some of my other local stuff, but not the android one. And since this is working fine in my other projects, I'm not sure what could be going on. **Perhaps they are checking a different local Maven repository?**

I recently installed Maven so I could create my own local repository for use when working on a library project. Maybe I somehow overwrote the original android directory? Doesn't explain why the other old libgdx projects are not failing to find the library though. How can I check where they are searching for it?

Here's the build script (generated by libgdx project generator):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/raw/maven-repo/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta-01'
    }
}
```

Here are relevant parts of build.gradle in top level of project and from the android module:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Comment: The support libraries don't get installed to your local repo as far as I can tell. It should be checking the SDK /extras/android/m2repository. Maybe a dumb question, but are you applying an Android plugin (application or library)? If so, can we see the whole build script?

Comment: Also please show us any relevant environment variables as well as your build script.

Comment: I added the build script. Not sure which environment variables are relevant.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Please post your build.gradle part .

Comment: I know this is not a direct answer, but I would seriously consider dropping gradle and producing a pure maven build. If you've been using android studio you might be reluctant to move away but I think it's better. It took me a long time but I have an example POM if you need it.

Comment: @Richard thanks but I can't afford the time to maintain that. Libgdx uses a slew of libraries, and I need to keep the iOS related ones up to date because they are still getting critical updates on a frequent basis. And I use several other libraries from Maven Central. Just doing development in my spare time.

Comment: You posted an answer about the escaping in your local.properties file and then deleted it; did that not fix your problem after all? Could you elaborate? I think that was a good thing to investigate.

Comment: The problem came right back when I exited and reopened Android Studio. Android Studio manages that file anyway, and it was back to how it looked before. I think there might be some kind of mixup going on because I have multiple Android SDK's installed due to using both Eclipse and Android Studio, and yet another from the Android Studio alpha or beta. I'm deleting all of them and reinstalling Android Studio to make sure.

Comment: Does your local.properties file (if exists) specify a path to a different sdk than the one containing the support library?

Comment: No, it points to the right one. I have now removed all copies of the Android SDK except one. I still have multiple Maven repositories though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check you Android sdk folder.**

You should find this folder under this:

```
androidSdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/20.0.0
```

If this folder doesn't exist:

- update the SDK Manager and update the Android Repository (the last block).

Also I suggest you using the last releases:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
```

Comment: It's all there in the Android repository in the sdk, and they are working fine in my other projects. Note the error in my question-- I think it is searching in the wrong local maven repository. I think I'm going to start a new project and copy stuff over one-by-one to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Which folder did you config for your local maven?

Comment: I don't know why android repository isn't found. 
May be it is an hack workaround. Try to add another maven url like:

maven { url "/sdkpath/android/extras/android/m2repository/" }

Comment: I accidentally fixed the issue by uninstalling all my copies of the SDK and reinstalling Android Studio. But your post was the most helpful and was getting me on the right track regarding where the Maven repository should be linked, so I'm awarding you the bounty.

Comment: And now, when I restarted Android Studio, the issue came back. But I tried your hack and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Please compile with this

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
```

Instead

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
```

Comment: No effect. That's how I originally had it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 okay . did you set  minifyEnabled false in your build.gradle

Comment: @Tenfour04 In my application , i used com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0 . Please set this .

Comment: No effect with that either.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed this after uninstalling Android Studio and the previous beta version I had, as well as all copies of the Android SDK on my computer. Then I reinstalled a fresh copy of Android Studio with the SDK.

Since none of the project configuration changes I made helped, I think there was possibly some kind of internal configuration in Android Studio that made it point at the wrong Maven repository, possibly the Maven repository in an Android SDK somewhere that was no longer maintained.

I'm glad I didn't reconstruct the project from scratch (to find step-by-step what differed between the problematic project and others that did work). Much faster to reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: Yep, I'm having the same issue and I believe this is my only solution too.  I deleted the support library and then tried to re-install.  It just will not find the library again after re-downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the mavenCentral repo:

`mavenCentral()`

to your `allprojects`

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Sidenote: the support libraries have been updated (not sure if you need the most recent ones):

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'`

Comment: I tried that with no luck. I think the support libraries are pulled from the local maven repo (which is why the SDK has to have Google Repositories installed). And so the problem is that somehow the library isn't getting populated into my local maven repo, or I somehow have multiple local maven repoes and it's looking at the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you have updated 'Android Support Repository' and 'Android Support Library' in your Android SDK Manager. Once updated, you should be able to build with latest `appcompat-v7`, at this time 21.0.3.

It would be more tricky for older `appcompat-v7` versions. We had the same problem before, we were using `appcompat-v7:19.0.+` at the time. It appears that once you update Android Support Repository & Library from Android SDK Manager, which contains the source for your support libraries, there is no going back. Once updated, it will only contain the latest source for support libraries, which means your build will always fail unless you update your `build.gradle` to point `appcompat-v7` to latest version.

I find it surprising that we cannot have multiple versions of `appcompat` available, like how the SDK manager handles the multiple version of Android SDK build tools.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds support library not installed or not in the right path as Android Studio supposed, so double check:

1. Check your Android SDK location from: `File->project Structure->SDK Location`
2. Then go to `SDK Location` path to check if `\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat` available
3. If not available then start `SDK Manager` under `SDK Location`, install both `Android Support Library` and `Android Support Repository` under `Extras`